# Copy link for launch Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I installed Anaconda and Jupyter Notebook. When I launch from Jupyter Notebook I see such a message "copy and paste one of these urls". How can I copy thess urls? I tried to click with the right button, left button, double click. Nothing helps, there is no interaction with the open window. I use Windows 8.1.

Can you please tell me why this window is not active and how can I copy the URL?

[prtscr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ze3xN.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could either click on the Python icon in the top left corner of the window to get into the edit menu. (Select + Copy) or you could use Ctrl + M to select and Ctrl + C to copy.

But usually the browser is supposed to open itself and go to the notebook.

HTH